# Multiple Database Connection on Directus

Tags: database-connection, directus

Can we connect to multiple databases on directus simultaneously?

I wanted to connect postgres, SQL and aws at the same time on Directus

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The closest the Directus team has come to discussing multiple database management has been this thread on their Github:

https://github.com/directus/directus/discussions/12699

As per the last message by a maintainer:

> This is not something that's officially supported [...] Directus wasn't designed to handle this use case out of the box

Within that same thread a user had manually modified the usage of Knex to use pools to connect to different Databases but it seems unreliable.

Currently the best way to get the benefits of using Directus with multiple databases is to set up a server with multiple instances of Directus running, each pointing to a different database, and using NGINX to access each Directus instance under a separate sub-path.

For example if you have your app data on Postgress and create reports on a separate MySQL database, you could setup NGINX to proxy one Directus connected to Postgres to `/api` and another Directus connected to MySQL to `/reports`.

---

Some useful links:

https://learndirectus.com/how-to-manage-multiple-projects-in-directus/

https://github.com/directus/directus/discussions/4480

https://github.com/directus/sdk/issues/51